# Google Charts - Change the color of the 'more' link

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I've made a couple of charts (pie and bar) and due to space limitations they needed to be re-sized which resulted in the addition of a "1/2 ▼" for the legend part.

I added my code here: http://codepen.io/qtx/pen/EtHvi
And in case my problem doesn't show up correctly here is a screenshot from my site, https://i.stack.imgur.com/C45fQ.png with a circle around what I want to change.
(it also shows up in the bar chart if I go beyond 8 columns, like in the above example)

So my question, is there any way I can change the color of that text/link? I can't seem to find anything online or in the api docs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
        ['Set 1', 215],
        ['Set 2', 83],
        ['Set 3', 132],
        ['Set 4', 72],
        ['Set 5', 260],
        ['Set 6', 34],
        ['Set 7', 9],
        ['Set 8', 24]
        ]);
        // Create the data table.
        var data2 = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Genre', 'Set 1', 'Set 2', 'Set 3', 'Set 4', 'Set 5', 'Set 6', 'Set 7','Set 8',{ role: 'annotation' } ],
        ['18/7', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, ''],
        ['23/7', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ''],
        ['24/7', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, ''],
        ['26/7', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, ''],
        ['29/7', 0, 0, 0, 0, 260, 0, 0, 0, ''],
        ['31/7', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ''],
        ['2/8', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, ''],
        ['3/8', 0, 0, 132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
        ['4/8', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, ''],
        ['8/8', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
        ['13/8', 0, 83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
        ['14/8', 215, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
        ['15/8', 0, 0, 0, 72, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
        ['16/8', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 34, 0, 0, ''],
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {
        title: '% of photos', fontSize: '12', backgroundColor: "transparent",
        colors: ['#F56363', '#eda15f', '#40C1A0', '#FFD586', '#81CFE0', '#fcfcfc', '#A06C90', '#FFCAD1'],
        };
        // Set chart options
        var options2 = {
        title: '# of photos', backgroundColor: "transparent",
        colors: ['#F56363', '#eda15f', '#40C1A0', '#FFD586', '#81CFE0', '#fcfcfc', '#A06C90', '#FFCAD1'],
        legend: { position: 'bottom', maxLines: 3 },
        bar: { groupWidth: '99%' },
        isStacked: true,
        };

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
        var chart2 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
        chart2.draw(data2, options2);

      }
    </script>
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there's probably a way to do it programmatically, you can target the element with CSS:

```
<style>
    path[d="M811,150L823,150L817,162Z"] {fill: purple;}
```

or simply

```
    path[d^="M811"] {fill: purple;}
</style>
```

Comment: Could you explain to me where I should add this? I added it to my css but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I think I figured it out, M811 should be M273 for the arrow down, M246 for the arrow up. Could someone explain to me what M273, M811 etc stands for? And why isherwood saw a different number than me?

Comment: Glad you found it. This approach is a bit fragile as it depends on that element always having that attribute.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `legend.scrollArrows.activeColor` and `legend.scrollArrows.inactiveColor` to set these. `legend.pagingTextStyle.color` is also available.

In your case it would be something like:

```
var options2 = {
        title: '# of photos', backgroundColor: "transparent",
        colors: ['#F56363', '#eda15f', '#40C1A0', '#FFD586', '#81CFE0', '#fcfcfc', '#A06C90', '#FFCAD1'],
        legend: { position: 'bottom', maxLines: 3, scrollArrows: { inactiveColor: "red", activeColor: "red" } },
        bar: { groupWidth: '99%' },
        isStacked: true
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! Thinking if you could also point towards any documentation where you found this. Because I wasn't able to locate these details anywhere!